# Python 'Logger' module double-logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pycharm

### SOLVED:

### This issue has been solved by renaming of of my two loggers. My issue arose because i would do `log.getLogger` again in the main file. This caused 2 instances of the logger to be made. The solution is to remove the second call, OR rename one of the two.

I am attempting to setup a custom logger for my current project, and I am having difficulty with getting it to work properly outside of `__init__.py` file. The issue is that anything I log is logged twice.

My Code:

***__Init__.py***:

```
import datetime as date
import os
import platform as plt
import logging as log


prefsDirectory = 'prefs/'
prefsName = 'preferences.txt'
prefsLocation = prefsDirectory + prefsName
now = date.datetime.now()

# SETUP

if not(os.path.exists(prefsLocation)):
    if not(plt.system() == "Darwin"):
        os.mknod(prefsLocation)
        with(open(prefsLocation, 'w+')) as f:
            f.write('Log increment:\n' + str(1) + "\n")
            f.close()
            pass
    else:
        if not(os.path.exists(prefsDirectory)):
            os.mkdir(prefsDirectory)
        with(open(prefsLocation, 'w+')) as f:
            f.close()
            pass
        with(open(prefsLocation, 'w+')) as f:
            f.write('Log increment:\n' + str(0) + "\n")
            f.write('\nCurrent Date:\n' + str(now.day) + "\n")
            f.close()
            pass

with(open(prefsLocation, "r")) as f:
    data = f.readlines()

if not(str(now.day) == data[4]):
    data[4] = str(now.day)
    data[1] = str(0) + '\n'
    # print('This ran')
else:
    inc = str(int(data[1]) + 1)
    data[1] = inc + "\n"


with(open(prefsLocation, "w")) as f:
    lines = (str(item) for item in data)
    for item in lines:
        f.write(item)

dateC = "[" + str(now.year) + "-" + str(now.month) + "-" + data[4] + "]"
logDirectory = "logs/"
inc = int(data[1])
logName2 = str(dateC) + "-" + str(inc)
logName = logName2 + ".log"
logLocation = logDirectory + logName


if not(os.path.exists(logLocation)):
    if not(plt.system() == "Darwin"):
        os.mknod(logLocation)
    else:
        if not(os.path.isdir(logDirectory)):
            os.mkdir(logDirectory)

        with (open(logLocation, 'w+')) as f:
            f.close()
            pass


formatter = log.Formatter("[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s][%(module)s] : %(message)s \n", "%H:%M-%S" + "s")

handler = log.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel("DEBUG")

logger = log.getLogger("Main")
logger.addHandler(handler)
log.basicConfig(filename=logLocation, level=log.DEBUG, filemode="w",
                format="[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s][%(module)s] : %(message)s \n", datefmt="%H:%M-%S" + "s")

logger.info("[LOG NUMBER: " + str(inc) + "]")
logger.info("Found Settings file")
logger.info("Generated Log File")
```

***__main__.py***:

```
# IMPORTS

import logging as log
from main import variables as vrs


# VARIABLES

logg = vrs.logg
logg.addHandler(vrs.handlerMain)
log.basicConfig(filename=vrs.logLocation, level=log.DEBUG, filemode="w",
                format="[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s][%(module)s] : %(message)s \n", datefmt="%H:%M-%S" + "s")

with(open(vrs.prefsLocation, "r")) as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# BODY

logg.info('Program Loading Completed.')

# Make a data holding file.

vrs.makefile('prefs/data.txt', 'prefs/', "Data File")
```

***variables.py***:

```
import datetime as date
import logging as log
import os
import platform as plt


prefsDirectory = 'prefs/'
prefsName = 'preferences.txt'
prefsLocation = prefsDirectory + prefsName


with(open(prefsLocation, "r")) as f:
    data = f.readlines()

now = date.datetime.now()
dateC = "[" + str(now.year) + "-" + str(now.month) + "-" + data[4] + "]"


logDirectory = "logs/"
inc = int(data[1])
logName2 = str(dateC) + "-" + str(inc)
logName = logName2 + ".log"
logLocation = logDirectory + logName


formatter = log.Formatter("[%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s][%(module)s] : %(message)s \n", "%H:%M-%S" + "s")

handler = log.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel("DEBUG")
handler.set_name('Main')

handlerMain = log.StreamHandler()
handlerMain.setFormatter(formatter)
handlerMain.setLevel("DEBUG")

logg = log.getLogger("Main")



def makefile(filelocation, filedirectory, filename):
    if not (os.path.exists(filelocation)):
        if not (plt.system() == "Darwin"):
            os.mknod(filelocation)
            with(open(filelocation, 'w+')) as file:
                file.write('File Created:\n' + dateC + "\n")
                file.close()
                pass
        else:
            if not (os.path.exists(filedirectory)):
                os.mkdir(filedirectory)
            with(open(filelocation, 'w+')) as file:
                file.write('File Created:\n' + dateC + "\n")
                file.close()
                pass

    logg.info('Created file: ' + filename)
```

I am not sure what exactly causes the issue...I think it is something with defining a logger in the **init** file, and a second in the variables file.

If it helps, I will provide a copy of my file structure below:

```html
<a href="https://gyazo.com/5cb1221a65a9ad50adf2a355f92f90e4"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/5cb1221a65a9ad50adf2a355f92f90e4.png" alt="Image from Gyazo" width="315"/></a>
```

```html
<a href="https://gyazo.com/39f1b61ca09ed364080254a0f678db80"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/39f1b61ca09ed364080254a0f678db80.png" alt="Image from Gyazo" width="1280"/></a>
```

*[ I Do not seem to be able to input gyazo images into the post, can one of you community moderator people put them in for me? ALSO, the folder to look at the one called AoC2018 ]*

Comment: It looks like you're adding two handlers, which will cause two outputs.
Can you post a smaller version of your code, its hard to tell what exactly is going on?

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question. Instead, consider adding your own an answer. 
Also, don't marked "SOLVED", as this is already apparent from the fact that you accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jobevers aluded to in his comment, you are attaching two stream handlers to the 'Main' logger. First in the `__init__.py` and again in `__main__.py`. This also explains why your logging from within `__init__.py` is working correctly as `__main__.py` hasn't attached the second handler yet.

I suspect the reason you did not expect this behaviour is because you were expecting the loggers to be distinct. But the loggers you defined in `__init__.py` and in `variables.py` are actually the same. When you retrieve a logger using `logging.getLogger(logger_name)` with the same logger_name it returns the same logger. So when you call `logging.getLogger('Main')` in `variables.py` it still has the StreamHandler on it from when it was added in `__init__.py`.

Depending on what behaviour you want you should either give them distinct names or remove the second addHandler.

It should be noted that logger names follow a hierarchy. Log configuration for `my_package` will also configure logging for anything `my_package.model`, `my_package.views`, etc... The root logger is simply the logger with the empty string (`logging.getLogger("")`).

For more details I'd recommend just going through [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html).

Comment: @ZachA In your edit you mention `caused 2 instances of the logger to be made`, which isn't exactly correct. You have two distinct **references** to the **same** logger. A very simple example that showcases what I mean: https://gist.github.com/RiceKab/d7bf8dd551b46e7d0841a2aa87eb93ff